# All data NULL after executing statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, conditional-statements

Statement I used:

```
INSERT INTO table (addr2, addr3) 
    SELECT City, State 
    FROM table
```

I tried to reverse, but I don't know how.

I want to get my data back. All columns and fields are now `null`.

Comment: I'm not sure how an insert could do this but It sounds like you overwrote your data.  If that is the case then the data is gone unless you have backups of your table.

Comment: An insert statement will never overwrite data. All that happened was the insertion of a bunch or rows that have addr2 and addr3 potentially populated but have City and state null.  Just select from the table where City is not null and you should see your old data. You will need to delete manually the data you inserted to get back to the old state (or if you have a backup, you can use that). But to be clear the original data is still  in the table.

Comment: That's what I would have thought.  The question wording just made me think that they lost the original data.

Comment: @Hopper is right. An `INSERT` won't overwrite data. Was that statement part of a larger code block?

Comment: @EricBrandt No, I am new to SQL. I am a Business Analyst and I needed to move the city and state fields over to the addr2 and addr3 fields- basically just copying all the data from city and state and placing the data into the addr2 and addr3.fields

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? SQLite? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @TechieGirlinCali: in response to "I am new to SQL": if you haven't already, make a backup of your database.

Comment: @Rob I am using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: If you lost your database data somehow, you can check with DBAs if they have database backup which could then be restored. If not, I am afraid your data is permanently lost.

Next time, before you start doing anything with the live data, ask DBAs to give you only read access - that way you will be safe :)

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ... basically just copying all the data from city and state and placing the data into the addr2 and addr3.fields

If you want to replace all existing `addr2` with `city` and `addr3` with `state` in all rows of the table, you want `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE foo SET addr2 = city, addr3 = state;
```

... where `foo` is the name of the table.

Note, that will replace any values you previously had for `addr2` and `addr3`, so use this carefully. If you only want to replace `addr2` and `addr3` where they are `NULL`, you can do:

```
UPDATE foo SET addr2 = city WHERE addr2 IS NULL;
UPDATE foo SET addr3 = state WHERE addr3 IS NULL;
```

Or, perhaps:

```
UPDATE foo SET addr2 = city, addr3 = state WHERE addr2 IS NULL AND addr3 IS NULL;
UPDATE foo SET addr3 = CONCAT(city, ', ', state) WHERE addr2 IS NOT NULL AND addr3 IS NULL;
```

Or, depending upon what SQL engine you’re using, you can also use `ISNULL()`:

```
UPDATE foo SET addr2 = ISNULL(addr2, city), addr3 = ISNULL(addr3, state);
```

So, delete the rows that you just inserted and then `UPDATE` the remaining rows as appropriate. You may want to backup your data first, just to be safe.

Comment: Since OP is "new to SQL" you might want to point out that `UPDATE foo SET addr2 = city, addr3 = state;` is a bit questionable.  The fields addr2 and addr3 would normally hold additional address lines such as "Suite 1203" or "5th floor."  Putting city and state names in there is unlikely to be correct.

Comment: I tried this statement as Rob recommended:                                          UPDATE foo SET addr2 = city WHERE addr2 = NULL;
UPDATE foo SET addr3 = state WHERE addr3 = NULL;and everything is still NULL even all the other columns and fields such as Name, DBA, CC, COUNTRY, MIN_CH, MAX_CH, MAX_DATE, BEGEFFDATE... I don't understand how my INSERT statement could cause my whole table to become NULL. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: When you did `INSERT`, you created records where everything except `addr2` and `addr3` would be blank (since you didn’t supply any values for any fields except those). So task 1 is to delete the records you inserted. But, as camba1 said, your original records should still be there.

Comment: How can I delete all the records I inserted?

Comment: IIRC, SQL Server Management Studio has something akin to a “data grid” view that allows you to edit records directly, in which case you could select the affected rows and then delete them. Alternatively, you can write a `DELETE` query, supplying a `WHERE` clause with the criteria uniquely identifies the records you added. But be _very_ careful, because if you mess up your `WHERE` clause, you can delete records you didn’t intend. I might suggest you engage someone on your database team to clean this up, as reluctant as you might be to do that, so you don’t make things worse.

Comment: Yes, I'll just have to get some expert help with this, and my team knows that I am learning, so I'm sure it shouldn't be a big deal- I was just hoping to figure this out by myself (i.e., research, question boards, etc.) Thanks for your help!

Comment: That sounds like a plan. We’ve all been there, so don’t feel bad.